# Python Resource File Management

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, directory-structure

I am wanting to know a good method to access resource files in Python.  Right now I am using pkgutil.get_data(...), which works fine once the package is installed, however not in my development environment because I have 'src' and 'resources' directories as siblings.  I also keep the test_resources in another sibling directory, and would like the tests to be able to find the test_resources.  Is there a way to extend the search path for pkgutil?  A sample of my file structure is below:

```
├── resources
│   └── download
│       └── file
│           └── type
│               └── config.yaml
├── src
│   └── download
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── file
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── type
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   └── code.py
├── test
│   ├── test_x.py
│   ├── test_y.py
│   └── test_z.py
└── test_resources
    ├── test_resources1.yaml
    └── test_resources2.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing these paths to your pkgutil calls.

```
ResrcConfigPath = os.path.expanduser('~path/to/resources/download/file/type/config.yaml')

TestResourcesDir = os.path.expanduser('~path/to/test_resources/')
testResource1Path = os.path.join(TestResourcesDir, "test_resources1.yaml")
testResource2Path = os.path.join(TestResourcesDir, "test_resources2.yaml")
```